# Google Drive - how to retain files but reinstall Drive?

Tags: sync, google-drive

I have reinstalled Windows and I have a lot of data on Google Drive (~60 gb). I have backed up the contents of my Drive folder and put them in the same location on my hard disk after reinstalling Windows. Unfortunately, once I reinstall Drive it starts syncing all over again and overwrites the files on my hard disk which is redundant and a waste of time. I want Drive to keep the current files in my hard disk after I reinstall windows.

Dropbox has a solution to this problem ([Dropbox - how to retain files but reinstall dropbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/645575/dropbox-how-to-retain-files-but-reinstall-dropbox/756075?newreg=e4796e2beb9746d8992201774cd6b45a)). If you point Dropbox to the correct folder location, it doesn't do a redundant sync, which is the sensible thing to do.

Is there a way to do this with Google Drive? I came across a workaround ([Prevent Dropbox, Google Drive, Skydrive, files resyncing when reinstall operating system](https://superuser.com/questions/463125/prevent-dropbox-google-drive-skydrive-files-resyncing-when-reinstall-operatin)), but is there a built-in setting to do this? I would prefer not to use this 'hack', and it seems like an obvious feature that Drive should have (especially if Dropbox has it).

Comment: In the settings for google drive you can disable offline sync, i dont know if this works for the program as well but its worth a try

Comment: I couldn't find this setting. Also, I don't understand what 'offline sync' is. I thought sync was only possible when online.

Comment: This question is about a Google Drive client that is no longer supported. See the [tag:google-drive] wiki for details. Questions about the current Google Drive client  should use [tag:google-drive-file-stream].

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait a couple of minutes? You asked this question in 2016, but even back then they've added a comparison feature. All you have to do is install Google Drive into an existing folder.

Once you approve the installation it takes a couple of intense minutes, but eventually you should see something like:

[image]

This was reported [by this blogger](http://alauddinahmed.com/blog/connect-google-drive-to-existing-folder-finally-its-here), before this week's new major upgrade, which led to a new question: [How does the new Backup and Sync treat existing Google Drive users?](https://superuser.com/questions/1229785/how-does-the-new-backup-and-sync-treat-existing-google-drive-users)

Comment: I waited at least 5 minutes and if I remember correctly Drive re-downloaded and replaced existing files. Anyway, thanks for the blog link. May be helpful in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Since I haven't received any answers, it seems like there are only 2 options:

1) Rough it out and re-sync everything. [Google Drive doesn't have a feature to avoid redundant sync.](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/Tz7bZZZnKFU/13CKcUxBBQAJ) Very frustrating.

2) Switch to Dropbox, which is more expensive.