# How does the new Backup and Sync treat existing Google Drive users?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Google [has upgraded](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/introducing-backup-and-sync-google-photos-and-google-drive/) both Google Drive and Google Photos' softwares into a single software called "Backup and Sync". Until now one had to backup/sync everything into a special folder called "Google Drive". From now on one can backup/sync multiple folders without creating a special folder.

My question is - what about users which already use that special folder? What's the best way to stop using the existing Google Drive folder and put its contents in, say, Documents, without having to re-download/upload everything?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like unlike what all news site claimed, it does not change the old behavior, but adds something else.

The new feature is a **semi** sync as the new multiple folders do **not** use My Drive:

[image]

This means they won't sync to your other computers, only to Google Drive's webpage.

In other words, if you have multiple computers, then the only folder to sync between all of them is the good old Google Drive folder.

The only exceptions are files and folders on which you right clicked and chose to add to My Drive. Yes, just like files and folders that other users shared with you.

Answer (score 0):

Backup and Sync syncs a single folder just like the old google drive.  You can sync that folder to multiple devices and the sync is selective, meaning you can sync the entire folder with sub-folders or you can pick and choose a subset of the folders.  It's even possible to sync different subsets on different devices. Pretty much how google drive worked in that regard.

But there's more. You now can setup automatic backup of photos, music, and documents to your cloud storage. And you can now connect to multiple google accounts concurrently. That's a tremendous feature, meaning you setup cloud "silos"--one for personal, one for business, etc. Each silo uses a different google account, so it has its own storage allocation and its own special folder on your local drive(s).